# Hibernate data fetching

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is how I fetch data:

```
public static List<SubjectSubjectUsersUsers> getAllSubjectUsers()
    {
        List<SubjectSubjectUsersUsers> theList = null;

        Session session = ServiceLocator.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try{

            theList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT s.name as subject_name, u.name as user_name, u.surname as user_surname, su.id as id from subjects s "
                    + "join subject_users su on s.id = su.subject_id join users u on su.user_id = u.id")

                    .addScalar("subject_name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("user_name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("user_surname", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SubjectSubjectUsersUsers.class)).list();


        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally{

            session.flush();
            session.close();

        }


        return theList;
    }
```

The problem is when I update data manually in the DB, the fetched data is not changed. But when I reload the server and IDE it works. What could be the cause of the problem? I guess I used the session object in the incorrect way. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any second level cache?

Answer (score 3):

you need to set [CacheMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/CacheMode.html) to refresh

```
query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);
```

Your query will look like -

```
theList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT s.name as subject_name, u.name as user_name, u.surname as user_surname, su.id as id from subjects s "
                    + "join subject_users su on s.id = su.subject_id join users u on su.user_id = u.id")

                    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)
                    .addScalar("subject_name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("user_name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("user_surname", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SubjectSubjectUsersUsers.class)).list();
```

However it's a bad idea to update DB from outsite while using hibernate, otherwise you won't get benefits of hibernate cache.